# Double condition ifelse in combination with str_detect

Tags: r, if-statement, mutated

I want to create another column which gives 1 if one of the words in the pattern is present in the column RoleName OR FulltextDescription, this is because it might be that the RoleName only says 'VP' while the FulltextDescription says that the person is VP of the cyber department.

My code right now looks like this:

```
pattern <- paste(c("cyber", "Cyber", "technology", "Technology", "computer", "Computer"), collapse = "|")

IPEm <- IPEm %>%
  mutate(`Cyber Job` = ifelse(str_detect(RoleName|FulltextDescription, pattern), 1, 0))
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

OR `|` is a logical operator that works on booleans--things that are TRUE or FALSE.

You can't (meaningfully) use `|` on a column unless that column is boolean (or you want it to be treated as boolean).

You can `|` the results of `str_detect` because `str_detect` returns a boolean TRUE or FALSE:

```
str_detect(RoleName, pattern) |  str_detect(FulltextDescription, pattern)
```

You could also concatenate the text with `paste` and do a single `str_detect` on the combined text:

```
str_detect(paste0(RoleName, FulltextDescription), pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `ignore_case` and simplify the pattern:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pattern <- paste(c("cyber", "technology", "computer"), collapse = "|")

IPEm <- tribble(~RoleName, ~FulltextDescription,
        "VP", "VP of Cyber dept.",
        "VP Technology", "VP of Tech",
        "VP", "VP of cyber dept.",
        "VP", "VP Finance",
        "VP technology", "VP of Tech"
        )

IPEm %>%
  mutate(cyber_job = if_else(str_detect(RoleName, regex(pattern, ignore_case = T)) | 
                               str_detect(FulltextDescription, regex(pattern, ignore_case = T)), 1, 0))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   RoleName      FulltextDescription cyber_job
#>   <chr>         <chr>                   <dbl>
#> 1 VP            VP of Cyber dept.           1
#> 2 VP Technology VP of Tech                  1
#> 3 VP            VP of cyber dept.           1
#> 4 VP            VP Finance                  0
#> 5 VP technology VP of Tech                  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>